# RegEx : Pattern to match the first or only line if specific pattern is not found

Tags: .net, regex

I have written a RegEx pattern to match everything before the first occurrence of either a dot (.) or a comma (,).

```
RegEx.Match(input, @"(.*?)(?=,|\.)").Value;
```

But in case a dot or comma does not occur in the input, then I would want the RegEx to return the entire string.

Example:

Input : "Freeze, Police."

Output : "Freeze"

Input : "Aim. Fire"

Output : "Aim"

Input : "Roger that"

Output (expected) : "Roger that"

Could someone suggest me how should I change my RegEx pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add enter marks in your regexp,

```
((.|\r|\n)*?)(?=,|\.|$)
```

In regex "." does not include neither "New line" or "Carriage Return"
And for end of the line use $

And of course, if you don't want to process data in multi lines then just use this.

```
(.*?)(?=,|\.|$)
```

Comment: Hey Vinod, what order will be followed for matching the optional characters. Currently I'm extracting the portion of the string occurring before either comma or a dot or the end of line. What if along with this I also want to check for a colon. Ex. "Robert Downey Jr. as Tony Stark / Iron Man:" So here, I want the RegEx to first check for the colon, if found extract the portion before that. Else go for remaining tokens. Does RegEx follow an order of matching?

Comment: Hey Lucifer, this requires a conditional check, this will do ^(.*?)(?(?=(?:[^:]*\:)[^:]*$)(?=\:)|(?=,|\.|$))